# Problem sending HTML Mails using MAPI and Outlook

Tags: delphi, outlook, email, mime, mapi

I am trying sending HTML e-mails using MAPI calls in my Delphi Application.
When the client is Thunderbird if works fine. But when the client is Microsoft Outlook or Outlook Express I need to save the HTML code in a file and send it as the first attachment of my message, elsewhere the mail client interpret the HTML as text, showing the tags.
Sending HTML as the first attachment works only when no more attachments are sent, because if I send one or more attachments the first (HTML) is also showed as an attachment.

Does somebody can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Douglas.

Message OK:
[Ok http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e51dfa52f4.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e51dfa52f4.jpg)

Bad Message (with one attachment):
[Bad http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7e5689e2b9.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7e5689e2b9.jpg)

Comment: I solved the problem using OLE integration when the user e-mail client is Microsoft Outlook. When it is Outlook Express I remove the formatting and send the message in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find that Outlook/OutlookExpress can not handle HTML natively, it might just be that you are using a version of Outlook that isn't capable of, or isn't configured to default to HTML rich content by default.  Have you tried reconfiguring your Outlook/OutlookExpress options to select HTML rich text by default?

It looks like it's actually working, but that Outlook does not display things correctly.  An HTML email sent via a traditional email client, is actually mime-encoded, just as it shows there. In other words, you may find that if the email is sent, it appears fine on the other side, it's just a bug in outlook-express that you don't see the MIME attached content in the window, instead you see it as it is truly done internally, as a MIME encoded attachment.

Comment: Yes, when the message is sent it is displayed correct in the recipient client. But I send it over outlook express (and not directly from my application) only for the user be able to edit the message, then I need that the message be correctly displayed.